# Slideup and Slidedown to reveal a div

Tags: jquery

Can you tell me how I can slideup a div with a top and bottom border which then slides down to reveal the contents of another div. I would like the text in the content div to slide down at the same speed as the message-box bottom border.

The HTML is

```
<div id="message-box">
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, minim accusamus dignissim has at, nec esse quas postea in. Vide harum id mei, aperiam legimus delectus an est. Sit quidam verear voluptatum ad, vim definiebas reprimique cu. Eu sea bonorum meliore, possim albucius complectitur vel et. Eum ne ferri persius abhorreant, mel in probatus pertinax, ex usu meliore corpora.
</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
#message-box {
position:absolute;
left:20px;
top:40px;
height:450px;
width:200px;
background:#eee;
margin-left:0px;
text-align:center;
border-top: solid 1px #000;
border-bottom:solid 1px #000;

}

#content {
position:relative;
top:0px;
height:350px;
font-size:16px;
padding:20px;
color:#000;
display:none;
}
```

The Jquery is:

```
var speed = 500;

$('document').ready(function() {
$('#message-box').slideUp(speed).delay(50).slideDown('speed');

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual document object (instead of a String) is passed to jQuery in the selector for the ready function.  Also, the `#content` element has its `display` property set to `none`.  You need to show the content after the animation is finished.

```
var speed = 500;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#message-box').slideUp(speed).delay(50).slideDown('speed', function(){
       $("#content").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/AEzUk/1/

Answer (score 0):

`document` is not a string

replace

```
$('document').ready(function() {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

correct your code don't treat document as string and speed var as string ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var speed = 500;
$('#message-box').slideUp(speed).delay(50).slideDown(speed);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var speed = 500;

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#message-box').slideUp(speed).delay(50).slideDown('speed');

    });
```

Corrections in your jquery